# SWI-Prolog Split List into 3 with special conditions

Tags: prolog

I need a relation that splits list in 3 lists, writing elements in turn to every list.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] -> [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like a homework assignment tbh. I would suggest studying the reading material that your teacher provided you.

Comment: @gnat: What was unclear in this question?

Answer (score 4):

```
split_3([], [[],[],[]]).
split_3([A], [[A],[],[]]).
split_3([A,B], [[A], [B], []]).
split_3([A,B,C|T], [[A|T1],[B|T2],[C|T3]]) :-
    split_3(T, [T1,T2,T3]).
```

This works like this in cases where the number of elements in the list is not a multiple of 3:

```
?- split_3([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],L).
L = [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]

?- split_3([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],L).
L = [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

It is rather unusual to demand a list of exactly three elements. In that case a structure would be most probably more appropriate ; or just the arguments alone. But anyway:

```
split_3l(Xs, [As, Bs, Cs]) :-
   split_3(Xs, As, Bs, Cs).

split_3([], [], [], []).
split_3([X|Xs], [X|As], Bs, Cs) :-
   split_3(Xs, Bs, Cs, As).
```

Comment: How cleverly they rotate, but still keep their places!